# What might be wrong with my Nuxt / Docker / Traefik config?

Tags: docker, nuxt.js, traefik, strapi

For some reason I can't get this to work. I'm trying to forward /api to API container.

Error I'm getting:

nuxt             | [6:11:03 PM] Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80

nuxt             | at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1083:14)

I think /api is being redirected to 127.0.0.1:80 but I don't know why?

Traefik dashboard: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtV5R.jpg

nuxt.config.js

```
...
  axios: {
    baseURL: '/api'
  },
  server: {
    proxyTable: {
      '/api': {
         target: 'http://localhost:1337',
         changeOrigin: true,
         pathRewrite: {
           "^/api": ""
         }
      }
    }
  },
...
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik
    command: --api --docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - mynet

  nuxt:
    # build: ./app/
    image: "registry.gitlab.com/username/package:latest"
    container_name: nuxt
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command:
      "npm run start"
    networks:
      - mynet
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=nuxt"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/"
      - "traefik.docker.network=mynet"
      - "traefik.port=3000"

  api:
    build: .
    image: strapi/strapi
    container_name: api
    environment:
      - APP_NAME=strapi-app
      - DATABASE_CLIENT=mongo
      - DATABASE_HOST=db
      - DATABASE_PORT=27017
      - DATABASE_NAME=strapi
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=
      - DATABASE_SSL=false
      - DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_DATABASE=strapi
      - HOST=api
      - NODE_ENV=development
    ports:
      - 1337:1337
    volumes:
      - ./strapi-app:/usr/src/api/strapi-app
      #- /usr/src/api/strapi-app/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
    networks:
      - mynet
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=api"
      - "traefik.docker.network=mynet"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/api"
      - "traefik.port=1337"

  db:
    image: mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=strapi
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - ./db:/data/db
    restart: always
    networks:
      - mynet

networks:
  mynet:
    external: true
```

Comment: what did you do?

Comment: I would use Nuxt proxy like this(not the Nuxt server property)
https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options#proxy

`proxy: {
  '/api/': { target: ''http://localhost:1337'', pathRewrite: {'^/api/': ''} }
}`

The Nuxt server property is assuming you are using universal mode or selected a backend for Nuxt during create-nuxt-app.(someone correct me if I am wrong).

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a little late, but you should remove the proxy from the webpack-dev-server and instead set the right rules using labels on your api service.

So if you're using Traefik v2, the label on your nuxt service should be

```
labels:
  - "traefik.http.routers.nuxt.rule=Host(`myhost`)"
```

then the label on your api should be

```
labels:
  - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`myhost`) && PathPrefix(`/api`)"
```